# Reshaping Error in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python, and I am trying to execute the following code, but I get the following error:

```
im[:,:,0] = f
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (700,900,3) into shape (700,900)
```

Can someone assist me with it?

```
img = numpy.zeros((700, 900))

row_idx = 160
curve = []

count = 0
for i in range(0, 900):
                        contour.append((row_idx, i))


values, num_values = get_values(curve);


a = imread('20091016_seg1_26_18245948_1chop.png')
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)

size_vec = numpy.shape(img)

im = numpy.zeros((size_vec[0],size_vec[1], 3));
im[:,:,0] = f
im[:,:,1] = f
im[:,:,2] = f


for i in range(0, num_values):
        im[values[i].y, values[i].x, 0] = 0.0
        im[values[i].y, values[i].x, 1] = 1.0
        im[values[i].y, values[i].x, 2] = 0.0

imsave('OUTPUT.png', im)
```

(eliminated semicolons)

Comment: Argh! The semicolons! They BURN!

Comment: Apparently `f` has shape (700,900,3), while `im[:,:,0]` has shape (700,900), so you can't assign `f` to `im[:,:,0]`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to overly a horizontal line (contour) on my image. If I comment the im[:,:,0] = f and f = numpy.rot90(a, 2) lines, I get a black image with a green contour across it, not my image.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with:

```
im[..., 0] = f[..., 0]
```

The problem is that you were trying to put the whole `f` into `im[..., 0]`, giving the `ValeError` due to the dimension incompatibilty.

Comment: or simply `im[:] = f`, since the code has `im[:,:,0] = f; im[:,:,1] = f; im[:,:,2] = f` and `f.shape` is `im.shape`.